# How can I make sure a font-size goes down if the text spills out of its' container?

Tags: css

I have these `div`'s on my site and they contain text which is sometimes too wide to fit the `h4` elements within.

[image: "The Presentation" spilling out of its' container]

Right now I've applied these styles to this particular `h4`:

```
h4 {
  font: {
    family: "Nexa";
    size: 3.25em;
    weight: 600;
  }
  line-height: 135%;
  letter-spacing: 0.15rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

I'm using the `em` measurement to change its' size. Is there a more appropriate measurement for this situation?

EDIT EXPLAINING HOW MY QUESTION IS NOT A DUPLICATE: Using the viewport unit of measurement will not help in my situation considering my styles are interdependent. I've tried it to confirm.

Comment: a jsfiddle would be better which would showcase your problem and allow us to work with it to give a solution.

Comment: It isn't that complicated . I'd have to include the whole site because my CSS is interdependent which is overboard for the nature of my problem.

Comment: well, then an uncomplicated answer would be to debug and set the size which fits in.

Comment: Is it a bad idea to add a class on that one element and change its' `font-size` to make it fit? I could add a class if the title text matches an item in an array or something and change its' size.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Font scaling based on width of container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container)

Comment: @DustinPianalto Viewport scaling definitely won't help in my situation. **This is not a duplicate.**

Comment: Why won't viewport scaling work in your case?

Comment: I don't know but just applying it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this:

```
h4 {
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}
```

And you need to set the language in a ancestral HTML element:

```
<article attr1="valor" attr2="valor" ... lang="en">
```

or

```
<html attr1="valor" attr2="valor" ... lang="en">
```

See more:
[Css Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/h/hyphenate/)

Comment: I could do that, but do you think that would look a little weird? Maybe that's just me.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to use an `if ... in` conditional to check an array of problematic titles. This array contains titles that don't fit the container properly. If the site is in the array of those titles I apply a class called `smaller` to the `h4` containing the problematic title. I don't know if this was the best approach but it's solved the problem. Thanks to everyone who offered help!